# How to create an ASP.NET MVC Controller Extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to define an extension controller method.  Is this possible?  When I try it, it compiles, but I receive a 404, instead of a 200.

```
    public static ActionResult MyMethod(this Controller)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a static action method, so this won't work.

What you could do instead is create a base controller class with a public instance method:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyMethod()
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a module that handles some webhooks, which I want to make available via NuGet. If I require people to inherit from my base class, it will reduce utilization since you can only inherit from one class.

Comment: In that case, you may want to consider an [ActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like just writing an HttpHandler might be the way to go here, since it's more extensible. But you did answer the question as asked.